# Whitelist for Gmail

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement a white-list-based system in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22330/how-to-implement-a-white-list-based-system-in-gmail)

Is there a way to tell Gmail "Only allow into my inbox emails from the following email addresses. Send the rest to the trash bin."? I know how to blacklist specific email addresses by making a rule such as "If the sender is from a specific email address, send it to the trash" but I can't make a rule for every email in existence except the ones I want to let through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`-` operator](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190). For ex. you can create a filter that says move all emails `from:(-@abc.com)` to trash. This will move all emails that are not from @abc.com domain to trash.

[image: Gmail Filter]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible as Google doesn't apply their filters in a certain order or have a built in option for this type of setup. That said I'm pretty happy with gmails junk filters...

Answer (score -2):

Gmail has a spam filter...

- Follow the `Settings` link in Gmail
- Go to `Filters`
- Create a new filter
- Type the email addr under `From:`
- Type just the domain name to whitelist the entire domain
- Click next step
- Make sure the `Never send it to Spam` is checked
- Click `Create Filter`