# How to make Gmail receive email only from one account?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement a white-list-based system in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22330/how-to-implement-a-white-list-based-system-in-gmail)

I want to make my Gmail account filter out all incoming email, save for those from a particular address, so that only email from that one address can be received, while the rest should be put automatically into trash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `from:(!%sender%)` to filter all emails but the ones from a particular sender. For example, if you only wanted to receive emails from Facebook, you would use `from:(!facebook)` in a filter that trashes all matching emails.

To add such an example filter, put `!facebook` inside the "from" field when creating filter options.